# A bird, a fish, a star. Wait what?

Tags: word, visual

Very punny.
1. [image: Two evil birds staring into your soul]
2. [image: I don't... what is this?]
3. [image: I've got a jar of dirt- and guess what's inside it!][image: now that's just nasty.]

> What punny word does each image represent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that I have 1 and 3 for sure, but reaching hard for 2:

1:

> Doubloons (double loons)

2:

> Hamster (ham-star)

3:

> Jellyfish (fish in jelly, since it comes with peanut butter)

Disclaimer: It's equally likely that I have all 3 horribly, horribly wrong.

Comment: Looks like I need to find longer phrases and harder, more obscure words :^)

Comment: To be fair, I thought 2 was wrong and it took me quite a while for 1. Great puzzle @iiiidk :D